# From TableView to DetailViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, detailsview

i have a TableView with some Names.
And i want to show these Names on an other ViewController, but i don´t get it.

Here is my code:

AnguckenViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {


UIViewController *DetailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];


AnguckenViewController *DetailKey = [self.originalsource objectAtIndex:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];

const char *cPlainKey = [DetailKey cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *plistPath;
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];



NSString *pszDetailValueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",szSafeKey];

NSString *szDetailValue = [temp objectForKey:pszDetailValueString];



[DetailViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:DetailViewController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

}

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *BackButton;
    NSString *_pszKey;
    NSString *_pszValue;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pszKey;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pszValue;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *keyLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *valueLabel;


@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize pszKey;
@synthesize pszValue;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        _keyLabel.text = _pszKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the pszKey property of the view controller, e.g. the DetailViewController,  before you display it modally.

```
DetailViewController.pszKey = @"The value";
[DetailViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:DetailViewController animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

And also in the viewDidLoad, it is good to use the getter of the properties instead of accessing the instance variables directly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.keyLabel.text = self.pszKey;
}
```

Comment: I set "pszKey" in the property of the DetailViewController, when i want to synthesize "pszKey" in "AnguckenViewController" i get an Error.

Answer (score 0):

So finally it works,

i changed the line:

```
 UIViewController *DetailViewController = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

to:

```
DetailViewController *DetailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

Thanks